# Sql Server 2012 Express Remote Access Connection String

Tags: c#, tcp, sql-server-2012, remote-access, sqlconnection

I have two computer on my home network and one of them (ELSA) keeps sql databases. The other one (NEXIS) has VS2010. I need to access databases via NEXIS whenever I am at home and outside. Now I have static IP number on my ISP. And ELSA has static IP on my router too (192.168.1.XX). I set up SQL Server Network Configuration>>Protocols for SQLEXPRESS>>TCP/IP Status "Enabled" and IP settings to enable remote connections. I opened TCP port 1433 on Windows Firewall and forwarded this TCP port on my router to ELSA's IP address. Also I checked if TCP port is open via Simple Port Tester and status is OK. I also enabled Named Pipes. SQLEXPRESS Authentication Methot is Windows Authentication. Now I have two questions:

1-

```
SqlConnection scnn;
SqlConnectionStringBuilder cns;
SqlCommand cmd;
SqlDataAdapter dap;
DataSet das;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        cns = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        cns.DataSource = "192.168.1.XX,1433";
        cns.InitialCatalog = "TempDB1";
        cns.IntegratedSecurity = true;
        cns.PersistSecurityInfo = false;

        scnn = new SqlConnection(cns.ConnectionString);

        cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from ID_Table", scnn);

        dap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        das = new DataSet();

        dap.Fill(das, "ID_TableDS");

        dataGridView1.DataSource = das.Tables["ID_TableDS"];
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hata");

        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

That is my code on NEXIS but I got errors. What is the problem?

2- If I want to access ELSA when I am outside, What should be my connection string?

Thank You.

Comment: _I got errors_.... my crystal ball is out of service today. Do you mind explain what are these errors.

Comment: And if you want to access your ELSA computer from the outside your local LAN you need to know the external IP address of your router and configure it to forward the calls to port 1433 to your ELSA computer. If it is a static IP valid on Internet (not in the 192.160.0.xxx range) then you could use it otherwise you need some dynamic dns service that associate your dynamic IP with a domain name. So this second question is off-topic on SO.

Comment: provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 (This section of message on my language but I can translate as "Connection timeout has expired or a connection to other server could not be made.")

Comment: Usually SQL Server Express creates a named instance when installs. Try to change your DataSource to 192.168.1.xxx\\SQLEXPRESS (No need to specify the default port)